# Unit testing kill command

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing, posix, kill

So I am trying to do something bad and dirty ;)

I want to call kill(0, SIGKILL) in my check unittest to kill child processes I launched with this test.

```
ck_assert_int_eq(magic(13), 13); //<- success, but I cannot stop magic now
```

if I do

```
ck_assert_int_eq(kill(0, SIGKILL), 0);
```

I get "test: (after this point) Received signal 9 (Killed)"

Are there ways around it? 
kill(0, SIGKILL) also done in the actual code, so I think if I try to call destruction function from my test, I am going end with the same error.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected behavior is.

Comment: Don't use SIGKILL if you can avoid it.  When you do use it, don't use a first argument of zero, and do use `fork()` to create a child and have the child commit suicide.  If you still must test `kill(0, SIGKILL)`, you still use `fork()` but you have to isolate the child from its original process group (`setsid()` or perhaps `setpgrp()` or `setpgid()`).

Comment: @a3f I want to initialise magic, check return code from initialisation, and then kill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> int  kill(pid_t pid, int sig)
>
> If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the 
>   calling process.

Source: `man 2 kill`

You need call `kill( child_pid, SIGKILL)`, because `child_pid == 0` will kill parent + child.

> pid_t fork(void);
>
> Upon successful completion, fork() shall return 0 to the child process and 
>   shall return the process ID of the child process to the parent process. Both 
>   processes shall continue to execute from the fork() function. Otherwise, -1 
>   shall be returned to the parent process, no child process shall be created, 
>   and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

Source: `man 3 fork`

Comment: You just need to add a bit of explanation — like `kill(0, SIGKILL)` is a bad idea and `fork()` plus `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)` in the child might be what's needed.